# User defined functions from Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to trigger user defined function from within Firefox?

I've tried this, with no luck:

```
var window=window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).
             getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation).
             QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem).
             rootTreeItem.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).
             getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow).
             getBrowser().
             selectedBrowser.
             contentWindow;
// user function defined in frame
window.frames[1].someFunction(arg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `window.frames[1].wrappedJSObject.someFunction(arg)`, presumably.